# Scroll over datagrid with click drag

Tags: wpf, scroll, datagrid, drag

I have a datagrid, this is loaded by a xml file... no problem.

I need allow scroll when user drag over all datagrid, or select row and drag up or down to scroll content.
I have de scrollbar but, this app is for touch screen so is more easy drag on datagrid to scroll.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. Handle the **Drag** event of datagrid and scroll the datagrid programmatically.

```
// hook up the row events during the loading row event for the datagrid
   private void MyDataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
   {
        e.Row.DragOver += new DragEventHandler(MyRow_DragOver);
        e.Row.Drop += new DragEventHandler(MyRow_Drop);
   }

   private void MyRow_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
   {
        DataGridRow r = (DataGridRow)sender;
        MyDataGrid.SelectedItem = r.Item;

        // Scroll while dragging...
        DependencyObject d = MyDataGrid;
        while (!(d is ScrollViewer))
        {
            d = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(d, 0);
        }
        ScrollViewer scroll = d as ScrollViewer;

        Point position = MyDataGrid.PointToScreen(Mouse.GetPosition(r));

        // create this textbox to test in real time the value of gridOrigin
        textBox1.Text = position.ToString();

        double topMargin = scroll.ActualHeight * .15;
        double bottomMargin = scroll.ActualHeight * .80;

        if (position.Y * -1 < topMargin)
         scroll.LineUp(); // <-- needs a mechanism to control the speed of the scroll.
        if (position.Y * -1 > bottomMargin)
         scroll.LineDown(); // <-- needs a mechanism to control the speed of the scroll.
    }
```

Comment: are you missing `MyRow_Drop`?